# Optimizing Double foreach loop

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a double foreach loop and want to speed it up by making it one loop instead of two.

The idea is that it takes one element from the dictionary and compares it against all elements in the dictionary

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Int64, string> kvp in originCounts)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Int64, string> testkvp in originCounts)
    {
    //Run Comparison on testkvp ad kvp
    }
}
```

I want to turn this into one loop, any suggestions?

Comment: and in what way do you wish to compare it? if it is anything other than "by key" then you can't really do it in anything other than O(N^2) - or maybe half that if you wanted to get elegant (but half of O(N^2) is still O(N^2)). We need to see what you are trying to do to comment, basically.

Comment: What is your purpose? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe you can play a bit with `.Distinct` extension method, to let the framework do the job?

Comment: A single loop does not mean faster.

Comment: Quantum Computing to LINQ ??

Comment: What I mean is that there is maybe other approaches, maybe using Distrinct (as Honza Brestan) suggested. I like the Distinct approach, not for the performance benefits, but because of the clarity of the code, and the confidence in Microsoft's optimizations.

Comment: Actually Distinct would be implemented using a set membership test probably backed by a hash lookup so it would be order(N) or so if the hash lookup is O(1) but as noted a dictionary is allready distinct on the keys so hmmmmmmmmm.

Comment: It's still unclear what you want. Maybe you could fill in the `//Run comparison...` part.

Comment: really I want to compare multiple things, let me ask a new question that is more specific
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400536/optimizing-foreach-loop-that-compares-multiple-things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) to check if all elements are the same:

```
var firstID = originCounts.First().Value.UserID;
bool allEquals = originCounts.Skip(1).All(o => o.Value.UserID == firstID);
```

It seems that this is what you actually want.

I've just picked out a field of your class in the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400536/optimizing-foreach-loop-that-compares-multiple-things) that sounds as a reasonable identifier.

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**: According to your comment you  want to determine if *any* of the objects' fields is different to the same field of another object.

```
var first = originCounts.First().Value;
bool allEquals = originCounts.Skip(1).All(o =>
                o.Value.FirstName == first.FirstName
             && o.Value.LastName  == first.LastName
             && o.Value.UserID    == first.UserID
             && o.Value.Address   == first.Address);
```

Comment: doesn't this just check against the first?

Comment: @Badmiral: Yes, but if not _all_ elements are the same  it would also return `false` on the first compared to the different. So you don't need to compare all with all but only the first with all.

Comment: Yes, I want to implement it such that for each one, I know which ones are the duplicates (as those are important for my purposes).   Is there anyway to implement this to compare against all for ANY value?  (I also want to know whether it is equal to any of the elements of MyObject.  Thanks!

Comment: @Badmiral: So you want to return false if any of the objects' fields is different to the field field of another object? **Edit** Edited my answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this with linq syntax and compare performance

e.g.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<long, string> kvp1 in originCounts.SelectMany(kvp1 => originCounts.Select(testkvp => kvp1), (kvp1, kvp) => kvp1)) {

}
```

or

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<long, string> kvp1 in from kvp1 in originCounts
                                                 from kvp in originCounts.Select(testkvp => kvp1)
                                                 select kvp1) {
}
```

Comment: all that does is use a different syntax; this doesn't make it any less *work*, and could very easily make it perform worse. Frankly, the nested-`foreach` is also easier to read and understand. I can't think of any good reason to do this...

Comment: I'm agree with you Marc, readability is very important.Nested foreach are easier to read and understand

Answer (score 0):

You can create a comparable string key value class that implements the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) interface.

```
public class ComparableString : IComparable
{
    public Int64 Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        string otherString = obj as ComparableString;

        if (otherString != null)
        {
            // PLACE YOUR COMPARE LOGIC HERE
            return this.Value.CompareTo(otherString.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Comparable String");
        }
    }
}
```

After doing that you can create a linked list and run the .sort method

```
var originCounts= new List<ComparableString>();
// Logic to fill your list
originCounts.Sort();
```

The average complexity is O(n(log n)) for the .Sort method and the worst case is O(n^2) see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx for more information.

Once you call the .Sort() method you'll know that any value before the index of your item is less than or equal to the value of your item, and any index greater than the index of you're at is greater than or equal to the value of your item.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm oversimplifying this by misunderstanding the question, but if you are just trying to find duplicate Values in a string, you can use the Values property of the Dictionary, and do a Distinct on them.

Using your example of a Dictionary:

```
    Dictionary<Int64, string> originalCounts = new Dictionary<Int64, string>();
    for (Int64 i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        originalCounts.Add(i, i.ToString());
    }
    originalCounts[5] = originalCounts[3];

    foreach (var kvp in originalCounts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (var value in originalCounts.Values.Distinct())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, to get the distinct objects (Which does not implement IComparable or override Equals and GetHashcode):

```
var noDups = originCounts
                                 //Any Prop. you want to compare
              .GroupBy(o => new { o.FirstName, o.LastName, o.UserID, o.Address })
              .Select(g => g.First())
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to compare a dictionary entry to the other entries in the same dictionary? Are you checking for duplicates? If so, you can use `originCounts.Distinct()`.

Edit: You would need to specify an `IEqualityComparer` for the `Distinct` method, otherwise it would only compare keys (which are always distinct in a `Dictionary`), not values.

Comment: If the KeyValuePairs are coming from a dictionary, the keys (at least) will all be distinct so `Distinct` won't filter anything out.

Comment: You're right, a comparer would have to be specified to compare the `Value` fields.