# Optimizing foreach loop that compares multiple things

Tags: c#, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Optimizing Double foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398909/optimizing-double-foreach-loop)

I am trying to turn a double foreach loop into a single foreach loop

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Int64, MyObject> kvp in originCounts)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Int64, MyObject> testkvp in originCounts)
    {
    //Run Comparison on testkvp ad kvp to see if all elements of object are the same
    }
}
```

And MyObject is defined as such

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anyway to do this using one loop? When they are all the same, I add them to a list of Int64.  It is the same dictionary.

Comment: And... what do you do when you find 2 item that have the same properties?

Comment: Is that the same collection/dictionary?

Comment: What means _same_ for your object?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do? Find matches? Compare if both dictionaries contain the same elements?

Comment: Define `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on the `MyObject` class, then add all objects from the `originCounts` to a `HashSet<MyObject>`. Now you can find duplicates by calling `Contains` on your set.

Comment: Why are you posting two same questions here (as @Magnus pointed out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `IEnumberable` of `KeyValuePair`s then you could do something like this:

```
public bool AreAllSame(IEnumberable<KeyValuePair<Int64, MyObject>> list)
{
  return list.Select(kv => kv.Value).Distinct().Count == 1;
}
```

Not sure whether it's really *optimized* but, it's shorter! :-]

Of course, whatever you're comparing will need to be comparable.

Comment: `Distinct()` would compare the *instances* not the property values.

Comment: Yes, which is why the object you're comparing would need to be comparable, as mentioned in my post. Otherwise it will use the default comparator which, as you state, will only compare that it is the same instance. :-)